# Clearing Collision Map of Planning Scene

Tags: ros, planning-scene, collision-map

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, 
Is there a simple way to reset the collision map of the planning scene?

I am running tests where I do arm motion planning in an environment, then move an obstacle and do motion planning again. When I move the obstacle, the planning scene still thinks the obstacle was in its old position. 
It looks like I am having a similar problem as [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/31202/updating-collision_map-in-planning_scene) where the collision map is being updated very slowly even after I move obstacles. 
I was hoping that it might work to just clear the collision map and then add in the obstacle at the new position.

I am moving obstacles by setting the planning scene with the SetPlanningSceneDiff service and I am using electric.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32782/clearing-collision-map-of-planning-scene/) by [clee2693](https://answers.ros.org/users/2182/clee2693/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Collision map updates are additive, so if you publish new obstacle information (e.g. point cloud) on an existing map, it will be displayed along with the previously available information.

If you're using one of the standard collision map implementations, you can explicitly clear the collision map via the `reset` service call, e.g., in a PR2 running the collider node, the service name would be:

```
/collider_node/reset
```

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0